# How do I count the number of occurences of a specific value in a group?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a bunch of data in groups in Crystal Reports. There's a status field, and for each group I want to display the number of occurrences of a specific status in the group footer.

Example:

```
==============
Group 1 Status
==============
Foo
Bar
Foo
Foo
Foo
Foo
Foo
Bar
Bar
Foo

----Number of occurrences of "Bar" displayed here-----

==============
Group 2 Status
==============
Bar
Bar
Foo

----Number of occurrences of "Bar" displayed here-----
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a new formula field:

```
IF {Status} = "Bar" THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

Then inserting a summary of the group sum of the formula field and suppressing it so all you see is the summary, which gives you an exact count of the number of "Bars" in each group.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of accumulator can be handled with three formulas. It's also possible to do this in SQL in many scenarios.

```
{@ResetBarCount} // Place this formula in the group header and hide it
global numbervar bar_count = 0;

{@IncrementBarCount} // Place this formula in group body and hide it
global numbervar bar_count;
if <DATABASE_COLUMN> = "Bar" then bar_count := bar_count + 1

{@BarCount} // Place this formula where you want to see your result
global numbervar bar_count;
```

My Crystal syntax maybe a little rusty so apologies if you have to tweak it.

Comment: For clarity, are you using  `bar_count` because I'm looking for "Bar" or is that just a coincidence? If I was looking for "Foo" would I use `foo_count`?

Comment: Oh, it's a variable isn't it? I can set it to whatever I want can't I? We're setting a global variable is what we're doing. Can you tell I'm new to Crystal syntax?

Comment: You're right. It's a global variable and you can freely change the name.